# Camel-Kafka component not workingfor error :"because of Brokers must be configured"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, stream-processing

Got an error using kafka component for Apache Camel (version 2.19.1),i'm just trying to print incoming messages in topic, my pipeline is so composed:

```
...
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("kafka://localhost:9092?topic=test&groupId=testing")
               .to("stream:out");
  context.start();
    }
}
```

tried with and without "//" in endpoint.

What i got is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[kafka://localhost:9092?topic=test&groupI... because of Brokers must be configured
at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:147)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3762)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3669)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3455)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3309)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:202)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3093)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3089)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3112)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3089)
at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3026)
at org.apache.camel.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Brokers must be configured
at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:62)
at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaEndpoint.createConsumer(KafkaEndpoint.java:76)
at org.apache.camel.impl.EventDrivenConsumerRoute.addServices(EventDrivenConsumerRoute.java:69)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:103)
at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:172)
at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:145)
... 12 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm trying to figure it out, but i really don't understand what's the problem, my kafka cluster is a single broker and all is  up and running (zookeeper and server), ty for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `brokers=localhost:9092` to the consumer uri.

Comment: Now i'm not getting any error but the consumer doesn't stay up, it exit with code 0, but instead it should stay up until an explicit context.stop() waiting for incoming messages, why?

Comment: Nope, by default (if you have a standalone Camel app) it shouldn't. There are solutions to keep the CamelContext running, check here: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: Either use Camel Main class as referred by @mgyongyosi

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this example](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/example/kafka/MessageConsumerClient.java) the first part of the URL is the `topic` and then as parameter you can pass the `brokers`. So the official documentation seems to be a bit misleading to me.

```
from("kafka:{{consumer.topic}}?brokers={{kafka.host}}:{{kafka.port}}"
                    + "&maxPollRecords={{consumer.maxPollRecords}}"
                    + "&consumersCount={{consumer.consumersCount}}"
                    + "&seekTo={{consumer.seekTo}}"
                    + "&groupId={{consumer.group}}")
                    .routeId("FromKafka")
                .log("${body}");
```

But as a general advice: Camel is [open source](https://github.com/apache/camel), so you can always have a look at the code and the examples there on github. You can also find those lines of the stack trace you posted there, then track down what's missing.

Comment: with this structure i dont' get any error, but the consumer doesn't stay up waiting for messages, but exit immediately with code 0

Comment: i used RabbitMQ component and i needed just endpoint informations to go, staying up and listening to the incoming stream, and other components i already used in past did the same, it has a default poll time interval in component itself, so i think it is not needed.

Comment: you are right. maybe there's a version incompatibility between this camel client and you kafka server?

Comment: i'm currently using the last version of confluent infrastructure, it is an option, i'll give a try.

Comment: once you found out that this is the answer you need, please accept it